# Should I include private methods into UML class diagram?

Tags: uml

So the question is simple. I just do not find the answer on the internet. I think private methods are useless in diagram, not telling much. But maybe I think wrong.

Comment: I think people will find your question off-topic and too broad for SO.

Comment: A UML diagram, like any other diagram, is a communication tool. What you should and should not include in your diagram depends entirely on what you're trying to communicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Private methods are an implementation detail of the class, not its public API.

**No**:

If you are using the diagram to show the external interface of the class, or some subsystem that the class is part of, then there is no reason to include them. They will just add visual noise and confuse the reader.

**Yes/Maybe**:

On the other hand, if you are trying to communicate the internal design of the class itself, or its tightly coupled collaboration with another class (think of `friend` in C++), then it might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

**Opinion:**

UML is not* a 4GL programming language. You use it to convey an idea, design, architecture. You only add information that serves that purpose. It does not have the concept of being "complete". Like text in a book, you only use words necessary for the purpose of conveying the message.

If it is used as part of system documentation, and it needs to show all members, then we just generate it afterwards.

UML is not the goal, it is just a modelling **language** to communicate with people.

So if it serves the purpose you add it, otherwise you leave it out.

*) some attempts have been made at that, but have not been very succesful (togetherJ springs to mind)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're modelling.

In general UML provides a mechanism to show operation (and attribute alike) visibility. As private feature can be depicted on a diagram it is clear that you **can** present it on a diagram. However if you show it or not depends what you're modelling. 
If you're modelling the internal behaviour of the class then yes.
If you're modelling just its external appearance you don't have to (but you still can).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should include them. It gives a bit more detail into how the class will work. IBM actually have a special notation for private methods - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/

Comment: The symbol for private scope (`-`) is not  a "special notation from IBM" it is part of OMG's UML specification.